# Sum of values for each row

Tags: mysql, join, sum

```
SELECT
ratings.programme_id,
programme.programme_name,
ratings.ratings
FROM
programme
INNER JOIN ratings ON ratings.programme_id = programme.programme_id
```

I have two tables a and b

a has id and name and b has id and ratings. There can be multiple ratings for each id in a. I want to calculate the sum of ratings for each id.

for example entry john has received ratings of 1,3 and 5 and I would like to get the sum which would be 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this, I did the following.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE myid(id INT, myname VARCHAR(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO myid VALUES (1, 'Paul');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO myid VALUES (2, 'Peter');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE myrating(ratename VARCHAR(10), therating INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.43 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO myrating VALUES('Paul', 3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO myrating VALUES('Paul', 4);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO myrating VALUES('Peter', 6);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO myrating VALUES('Peter', 456);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
```

And then performed the query

```
SELECT myid.myname, SUM(myrating.therating) AS The_Rating 
FROM myid inner 
JOIN myrating 
ON myrating.ratename = myid.myname 
GROUP BY myid.myname;
```

Obtaining the result:

```
+--------+------------+
| myname | The_Rating |
+--------+------------+
| Paul   |          7 |
| Peter  |        462 |
+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Does this satisfy your requirements?

Comment: thank you I had to adopt it to my database structure but it worked perfectly thanks

Comment: Thanks for the correct vote - you can make the query a little more elegant by doing something like the following "SELECT myid.myname, SUM(myrating.therating) AS Rating_Sum <rest of query identical...>, i.e. you can give your own alias to field name results using the AS keyword.

Comment: I did the formatting and demonstrated the AS word.